# Re-getting POP3 messages

Tags: vb.net, pop3

I am using [Peter Huber's POP3 client](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15611/POP3-Email-Client-with-full-MIME-Support-NET-2-0) to connect to gmail and download messages.

The inboxes being accessed are transactional inboxes used only for code-access. That is, a message comes in with a order file attached, code will process it and then delete the message. One stipulation of the code though was a DEBUG flag, which if set would prevent the code from deleting the message so that you can run the program again later without the debug flag and reprocess the message. So, in my code I have

`If Not Arguments.Debug Then pop.DeleteEmail(eid)`

This works fine. Problem is, even when not deleting the message, running the program a second time will not re-retrieve the message, even though if I login to gmail and look at the inbox, it is still there. The only way I can get the program to see the message again is to forward the message back to the same inbox. But in Peter's code I do not see anywhere where he is keeping track of seen messages between sessions.

Is this something that is done on gmail's end? Refusing to deliver a message to the same client a second time? If so, is there any way I can change my gmail account so that it will always show all messages in the inbox to a client when retrieving the list of messages, even ones already "seen"? I don't see anything in the gmail settings screen.

**UPDATE**: I tried adding a method to send a RSET command to the server, as per [this comment](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15611/POP3-Email-Client-with-full-MIME-Support-NET-2-0?msg=3477014#xx3477014xx) on the codeproject page. I then call my new `Reset()` method after retrieving my messages but before disconnecting, ... but I still have the same problem.

Comment: i first read this as "regretting POP3 messages" and i began to thing of all the emails i regretted sending

Comment: LOL - you're not the first person said that.  B-)  Hopefully the hyphen makes it clearer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... found a "sort of" answer after reading through pages of the comments on the codeproject project.

According to [this comment](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15611/POP3-Email-Client-with-full-MIME-Support-NET-2-0?msg=2680937#xx2680937xx), the RSET command does not actually do anything when you are dealing with gmail's servers.

The "answer" is to prepend your username with the string "recent:", so instead of logging in with [**myaccount@gmail.com**] you log in with [**recent:myaccount@gmail.com**]. Rather hackish, ... but it works.